# Mark a file/folder as deleted in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

In Visual Studio, I moved a few files and folders around.

When I try to check my project into my repository on VSTS, I'm getting an error that reads as below and fails to check my project in.

> "Could not find a part of the path..."

Looks like the issue has to do with those files/folders that I moved around. Funny thing is I did all that inside Visual Studio, hoping it would understand what I was doing and not give me this error.

Basically, the folder that VS is not finding is a folder that I moved to a new location. So it should see it as deleted in its old location and new where it is now.

Is there a way to mark a file/folder as deleted? How am I supposed to fix this error.

Comment: Is this TFVC?  What does your pending change list look like?  In particular, what are the pending changes for the paths in error?

Comment: Yes, it is TFVC. Basically the folder I moved still seems there in the list of items to be checked in. The files under that folder are marked for deletion i.e. their names have a line through them. But the folder doesn't have that line through its name.

Comment: What's the detail version of your VS? What's the detail steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: It's VS 2017 15.3.4. I was able to resolve this issue by creating the removed folder -- through VS UI -- then deleting it. I guess doing this somehow fooled VS into believing that the folder existed in the first place -- hence the original message. To be honest, I'm always nervous in VS because of such occurrences.